# TurboTable header checkbox selects all data in all pages and not only the current page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm using turboTable with primeNG version 5.2.2,

in a previous version I was using, the selectAll checkbox selected only the current page (wanted behaviour )

Now with this version the selectAll checkBox selects all data in all pages,

is there a way to fix this please ?

my html code :

```html
<p-table [pageLinks]="10" exportFilename="Boitiers" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [tableStyleClass]="cats-dataTable" (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="selectAll($event)" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
            (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" [value]="devices" [columns]="selectedColumns" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,50,100,200,500]" id="tableDevices" [(selection)]="selectedDevices"
            [emptyMessage]="'pas de resultats'" #dt>
            
            <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                    <div style="text-align:left">
                        <p-multiSelect [options]="cols" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns" optionLabel="header"
                                    selectedItemsLabel="{0} {{'catsApp.device.selectedItemsLabel' | translate}}" [style]="{minWidth: '300px'}" defaultLabel="{{'catsApp.device.defaultLabel' | translate}}"></p-multiSelect>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="{{'catsApp.device.exportAll' | translate}}" (click)="dt.exportCSV()" style="float:left"></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-file" iconPos="left" label="{{'catsApp.device.exportSelection' | translate}}" (click)="dt.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})" style="float:right"></button>
                    </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 38px">
                                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
                        </th>
                        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                            {{col.header}}
                            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 50px">
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 50px">
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 50px">
                            </th>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior expected, if you use lazy then what you want will happen.
All this happens because in lazy you have only the current page loaded, and non lazy you have all items paginated under the screen.